# asp.net forms authentication: public folder not allowing application access

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I have a website that I've recently set up with asp.net forms authentication. It is authenticating through Active Directory.  On the website are two folders which I've made public using location tags in the root web.config file, like this:

```
<location path="FolderA">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="FolderB">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

FolderA contains a PHP application that uses jQuery's ajax function to get json data from a controller which resides within FolderA.

FolderB contains a ClickOnce application (an Outlook add-in).

I am able to navigate to both of those folders in all current browsers without getting prompted to log in. If I go to other non-public areas of the site, I am prompted to log in.  That's exactly the way I want it.

But I have a few users on IE9 who have experienced failure when they hit a view in FolderA that tries to get the json data. The users, of course, aren't prompted to log in, but the data never loads, and there is an error message in the dev console saying access denied. Oddly, I am not able to duplicate this behavior with IE9 on my machine.

Additionally, when I try to install the ClickOnce application, it downloads and installs successfully, but when Outlook tries to load the add-in I get a message saying that authentication with the application failed. It used to work fine; the only thing that has changed is that I added forms authentication to the site. I've tried designating the folder as an application in IIS with anonymous authentication, but no luck.

I'm running IIS7, and the site is using .Net Framework 2.0.

I'm having trouble understanding this behavior, and I was hoping someone could give me guidance on how to address it. I'm pretty much at a loss and the users are getting restless.

Comment: Have you tried adding the site to the Trusted sites for IE9 users?

Comment: Yes, this is the first step we take before installing the ClickOnce on people's machines. Thanks!

Comment: Re the ClickOnce: Turns out one of our IT guys added a second binding to the website in IIS, which killed the ClickOnce web service call (WCF doesn't support multiple bindings for the same protocol for a website). That happened shortly after I implemented forms authentication, so it seemed like the ClickOnce problem was a result of implementing forms authentication, but the two issues were unrelated.  I still haven't resolved the ajax/json problem. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.